# names of some earthquake analysis methods

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

For structure earthquake analysis methods, do these all below mean the same thing, just ways of calling it differently?

1. Linear Response History Analysis
2. Linear Elastic Time History Analysis
3. Linear Time History Analysis
4. Response Spectrum Analysis

Or if there are differences, which one(S) is different?

Comment: Should you have improved this question? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/35299/10902

Comment: no, these are different questions, let that stay there, I am aware of that question, which I also asked. I want to know if these four methods here mean same thing or which one or ones are different.

Comment: Where is this terminology coming from? That could be significant in the answer. For example, 1, 2, and 3 "sound" the same to me, but if they are from the same source (such as a program), then there is some difference.

Comment: They come from different sources. Indeed, after asking the question, upon my further search, I realized that the first 3 are the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All are linear dynamic procedures. The first three are same thing. It uses an actual or synthetic earthquake record, to be applied to the structure. The load is introduced in very small time fraction increments such as 0.1 seconds or even less. After one step is done, next step comes. This makes time history method to be suitable for non linear analysis as well, because you can introduce nonlinear properties in each step.... The fourth one is different. It uses a response spectrum, for introducing loads into the building. We must use enough modes to have 90% of mass participating in response

Comment: FYI: I see this is your second answer, adding more detail than your previous one. I've therefore deleted your original answer. Next time, instead of adding multiple answers, simply [edit] your answer with any information you wish to add.